# How to use random_state=np.random.RandomState(0)

Tags: python, random-seed

I'm writing a function like this
`def split_into_train_and_test(x_all_LF, frac_test=0.5, random_state=None):`

The function is passed in like this
`split_into_train_and_test(x_LF, frac_test=0.3, random_state=np.random.RandomState(0))`

Currently I am using this to get the random seed, but it's not working.

```
if random_state is None:
       random_state = np.random
   else:
       np.random.seed(random_state)
       np.shuffle(x_all_LF)
```

How do I extract the random seed with np.random.RandomState(0).

Answer (score 0):

Just use `random_state` instead of `np.random` and the functions in the `np` namespace:

```py
if random_state is None:
   random_state = np.random
else:
   random_state.shuffle(x_all_LF)
```

The only methods that `RandomState` has that aren't available in `np.random` are dunder methods and `tomaxint`.